# Cleaning up a string

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, .net-3.5, string

I have the following string which I need to get onto one line for database storage and retrieval purposes:

```
{"id":8,"heading":"heading goes here","content":"<p>
    content goes here</p>
"}
```

I am using the following command to get this onto one line:

```
Dim strContent As String = Request.Form("strContent").Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "")
```

This puts the above string onto one line as follows:

```
{"id":8,"heading":"heading goes here","content":"<p>    content goes here</p>"}
```

However, within the string there seems to be a "tab" character

How do I get rid of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Request.Form("strContent").Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "").Replace(vbTab, "")
```

In fact I imagine you could use `vbCrlf` instead of the two replaces ie

```
Request.Form("strContent").Replace(vbCrlf, "").Replace(vbTab, "")
```

Although I would say that I think removing characters this way and then hoping to reinstate the original HTML could be fraught with problems. But maybe not. Depends on your particular issue.

If you are wanting to preserve these control characters and pass them to the client you could try something along the lines of

```
Request.Form("strContent").Replace(vbCrlf, "%0d%0a").Replace(vbTab, "%09")
```

This will make the chars safe for transmission with JSON.

Comment: I think I need to do this unless there is a better way.  When I extract the string from the database, it generates an invalid json object if the string contains any of the bits I am trying to remove.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`vbTab`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbtab.aspx) in the same way you used `vbCr` - there is also a `vbCrLf`:

```
Request.Form("strContent").Replace(vbCrLf, "").Replace(vbTab, "")
```

However, the database should be able to store text that includes a line and tabs - unless there is a specific requirement to clean the string up, you shouldn't.

By the way - this string is *not* HTML.

Comment: I think I need to do this unless there is a better way.  When I extract the string from the database, it generates an invalid json object if the string contains any of the bits I am trying to remove.